# How do I delay playing of HTML5 audio, but ignore the delay from loading the audio file?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, audio

I would like an HTML5 audio sample to play 10 seconds after a page has loaded, to coincide with a CSS transition on the page. This works fine locally, however when loading the web page in a live environment there is a 1-2 second delay as the audio is loaded and it seems the JavaScript below takes the 10 seconds from when the *audio* has loaded rather than from when the *page* is initially loaded.

Please could someone advise how I can make sure the audio plays 10 seconds in (which is plenty time to load the audio file itself) at the exact point the transition occurs, rather than taking the 10 seconds from when the audio itself loads?

The header which appears at 10 seconds:

```
h1
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 2.6em;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    font-size: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -1.3em;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    letter-spacing: -0.05em;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: -2px -2px 0 #ff6, 2px -2px 0 #ff6, -2px 2px 0 #ff6, 2px 2px 0 #ff6;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-animation: logo 5s ease-out 10s;
    -moz-animation: logo 5s ease-out 10s;
    -ms-animation: logo 5s ease-out 10s;
    -o-animation: logo 5s ease-out 10s;
    animation: logo 5s ease-out 10s;
}
```

The HTML for the audio:

```
<audio id="theme" preload="auto" controls>
    <source src="audio/sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function playtheme() {
    document.getElementById('theme').play();
}

function playaudio() {
    setTimeout("playtheme()", 10000);
}
```

Comment: are you displaying this into a webview?

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
window.onload = function() { // when the page loads
  setTimeout(play, 10000);  // set a 10 second timeout to call play()
}  
play = function() { // play the audio
  document.getElementById("theme").play(); 
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your response but this seems to suffer from the same problem.  I should have mentioned before that I have onload="playaudio()" in the body tag of the html.  So effectively my code is already doing the above.  What I really need is a way to load that one audio file first before the page does anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to know how long the load *will* take, so starting the animation before you know it's loaded may or may not line up with the audio beginning.

- If the most important thing is that the animation lines up with the audio beginning, you need to wait for the audio to load to begin your timer and animation.  Below, I've demonstrated this.
- If the most important thing is that the animation happens 10 seconds in, you should start the animation on page load and play the audio whenever it's done loading

This waits until the audio is ready to play to begin the timer.  If the load takes 15 seconds, the audio will take 25 seconds from page load to begin.

```js
(function() {
  // BEGIN: For debugging
  var counter = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    counter += 1
    document.getElementById('debugcounter').innerHTML = counter;
  }, 1000);
  // END: For debugging

  document.getElementById('theme').oncanplay = function() {
    // BEGIN: For debugging
    document.getElementById('loaded').innerHTML = "Yes";
    // END: For debugging
    
    // Create and append the h1 now, once it's able to play
    // This element has a animation delay of 10 seconds, so it will line up with the audio playing
    var h1Ele = document.createElement('h1');
    h1Ele.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This is the H1 whose animation is complete once the audio plays"));
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(h1Ele);


    var audioEle = this;
    
    // Play after 10 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
      audioEle.play();

      // BEGIN: For debugging
      clearInterval(timer);
      // END: For debugging
    }, 10000); // 10 seconds
  };
})();
```

```css
/* BEGIN: For debugging */
.debuginfo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.debuginfo p {
  margin: 0;  
}
/* END: For debugging */
@-webkit-keyframes logo {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes logo {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes logo {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes logo {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0;
  
  /*
    animation-name: logo;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-delay: 10s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 */
  -webkit-animation: logo 5s ease-out 10s forwards;
  -moz-animation: logo 5s ease-out 10s forwards;
  -ms-animation: logo 5s ease-out 10s forwards;
  -o-animation: logo 5s ease-out 10s forwards;
  animation: logo 5s ease-out 10s forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="debuginfo">
  <p>Loaded? <span id="loaded">No</span></p>
  <p>Time since page load: <span id="debugcounter"></span></p>
</div>

<audio id="theme" preload="auto" controls>
  <!-- Using deelay.me for debugging purposes.  This will delay the load for 15 seconds -->
  <source src="http://deelay.me/15000/http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/2534.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Alternatively, instead of maintaining "10 seconds" in both JavaScript and CSS, you can control it entirely in JS... see below:

```js
(function() {
  // BEGIN: For debugging
  var counter = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    counter += 1
    document.getElementById('debugcounter').innerHTML = counter;
  }, 1000);
  // END: For debugging

  document.getElementById('theme').oncanplay = function() {
    var audioEle = this;
    
    // BEGIN: For debugging
    document.getElementById('loaded').innerHTML = "Yes";
    // END: For debugging
    
    // Play after 10 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
      audioEle.play();
      document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].className = "audio-started";
      
      // BEGIN: For debugging
      clearInterval(timer);
      // END: For debugging
    }, 10000); // 10 seconds
  };
})();
```

```css
/* BEGIN: For debugging */
.debuginfo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.debuginfo p {
  margin: 0;  
}
/* END: For debugging */
@-webkit-keyframes logo {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes logo {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes logo {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes logo {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0;
}
h1.audio-started {
  /*
    animation-name: logo;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-delay: 10s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 */
  -webkit-animation: logo 5s ease-out 0s forwards;
  -moz-animation: logo 5s ease-out 0s forwards;
  -ms-animation: logo 5s ease-out 0s forwards;
  -o-animation: logo 5s ease-out 0s forwards;
  animation: logo 5s ease-out 0s forwards;  
}
```

```html
<div class="debuginfo">
  <p>Loaded? <span id="loaded">No</span></p>
  <p>Time since page load: <span id="debugcounter"></span></p>
</div>

<audio id="theme" preload="auto" controls>
  <!-- Using deelay.me for debugging purposes.  This will delay the load for 15 seconds -->
  <source src="http://deelay.me/15000/http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/2534.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<h1>Audio Began</h1>
```